# Prove that the Faber-Schauder System is a basis for $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, approximation-theory

I am trying to prove that the Faber-Schauder System is a basis for $C[0,1]$ but I am stuck at some point. I will define the relevant functions to my question and explain what I have done so far.

Let $s_{n,k}(x) = \max\{1-|2(2^nx-k)-1|, 0\}$. Let $g$ be a continous function defined on $[0,1]$ with $g(0) = g(1) = 0$. Let $g_{0} = g$ and $h_0 = g_0(\frac{1}{2}) s_{0,0}$. Then we inductively define for $n \ge 1$, $g_n = g_{n-1} - h_{n-1}$ and $h_n = \sum_{k = 0}^{2^n-1}g_n(\frac{2k+1}{2^{n+1}})s_{n,k}$. And finally, we define $t_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} h_k$. I proved by a series of induction that $t_n(x) = g(x)$ for $x \in D_n := \{\frac{j}{2^{n+1}}: j \text{ integer}, 0 \le j \le 2^{n+1}  \}$.

What I couldn't prove is that $t_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $[0,1]$. I believe it is sufficient to prove that $t_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $D = \bigcup_{n = 0}^{\infty} D_n$ since D is dense in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So: $t_n(x)$ is the piecewise-linear function that agrees with $g(x)$ on $D_n$.
Given $\epsilon > 0$, use the fact $g$ is uniformly continuous to take $n$ sufficiently large that for $|x - y| \le 2^{n+1}$, $|g(x) - g(y)| < \epsilon$, and use that to show
that $|g(x) - t_n(x)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I tried this idea but I got stuck. $|g(x) + t_n(x) | = |g(x) - g(a) + t_n(a) - t_n(x)| \le |g(x) - g(a)| + |t_n(a) - t_n(x)|$ for some $a \in D_n$ such that $|a-x| \le 2^{n+1}$. The uniform continuity of g defines n. So it must be fixed at this point. 
I don't know what to do with the other term. For that, I could use the fact that $t_n$ is uniformly continous but then I need to ensure a and x are close to each other (maybe they need to be closer more then they already are ). So I would need to change the initial choice of n and I would go back to the beginning.

Comment: Problem is that for each n, the delta for the uniform continuty of $t_n$ will vary.I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: If $j/2^{n+1} \le x \le (j+1)/2^{n+1}$, $t_n(x)$ is between $g(j/2^{n+1})$ and $g((j+1)/2^{n+1}$.  So $t_n(x) - g(x)$ is between $g(j/2^{n+1}) - g(x)$ and $g((j+1)/ 2^{n+1}) - g(x)$. If both of those are less than $\epsilon$ in absolute value, so is $t_n(x)-g(x)$.